# Trying to Remove table access full in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

i have a simple query

```
select round(sum(a.wt)) as a_wt 
from db.abc a 
where a.date is null 
and a.col_no is not null 
and a.pod_cd = '367' 
and a.fant != a.rce
```

and I want to remove table access full.there are 3 index which are like these on following combination of column

1. `col_no`
2. `col_no,date,fant,pyc`
3. `wagno,batno`

what can be can be done to  remove table access full.
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to remove `table access full`?

Comment: @Tejash to reduce  query cost

Comment: Are you sure that if you remove the `table access full`, you will get good performance? If you really want to remove table access full then apply indexes on all columns used in the WHERE clause but that will increase any DML operations on the table. Your second index is also not used? If no then CBO must have decided to do full table scan (and not using second index) as it may be less costly.

Comment: @Tejash this is a transactional table ,data will inserted into it, so if i want to put index on all where condition column how to do whether i keep all columns in where condition in a single index or define separate index for all columns present  in where condition in table.

Comment: Show us the execution plan of the query.

Comment: @Tejash image attached

Comment: How selective is the `pod_cd = '367'` predicate?  If that is reasonably selective, an index on `pod_cd` would likely be beneficial.  How selective is the `a.fant != a.rce` predicate?  If that happens to be highly selective, depending on the Oracle version it may be useful to do something with a computed column

Comment: How many rows does you table contain? For small tables (a few hundred rows, may low thousands) a full table scan is very often the most efficient thing to do. And why are you comparing numbers with strings?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be creating a <kbd>[`Function Based Index`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS258)</kbd> :

```
create index idx_date_col_pod on ABC (nvl("date",date'1900-01-01'), nvl(col_no,0), pod_cd);
```

and  convert the query to :

```
select round(sum(wt)) as a_wt
  from abc
 where nvl("date",date'1900-01-01') = date'1900-01-01' -- matching means "date" column is null assuming there exists no records with this ancient date.
   and nvl(col_no,0) != 0 -- non-matching means "col_no" column is not null
   and pod_cd = 367
   and fant != rce
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually indexes are not indexing the null values, so the conditions like

```
where a.date is null 
  and a.col_no is not null
```

meaning just "don't use an index in order to get lines for these conditions"

However, there is an option in the create index statement allowing it to index null columns (starting from version 11 as far as I know)

```
create index abc_date_nulls on abc(date, 1); -- (xxx,1) is doing the trick
```

Thus you'll create an index that considers null values. This might be useful depending on selectivity of "date is null" condition.

Otherwise or in addition, I'd suggest you to check the selectivity for the condition "pod_cd = 367" and build an index on pod_cd column.

If you are sure the index will help and the database doesn't use it, you can force oracle to use an index using a hint

```
select /*+ index(index name) */ ... from ...
```

It is good for tests or for checking the impact indexes can provide but pleasepleaseplease be careful using them in production. Google the documentation and all the things about disadvantages for that approach. Don't tell anyone I told you to use hints on production

Comment: Bitmap indexes use condition like `a.date is null` - however they are only suitable if you have low distinct values in that column. It may also cause problems in OLTP multi-user environments.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes can be used to check for nulls, and to compare two columns against each other.

Setup:

```
create table abc
( dt      date
, col_no  number
, pod_cd  varchar2(5)
, fant    number
, rce     number
, wt      number )
nologging;

insert /*+ append */ into abc (dt, col_no, pod_cd, fant, rce, wt)
select case mod(rownum,3) when 0 then date '2018-12-31' + mod(rownum,1000) end
     , case mod(rownum,7) when 0 then rownum end
     , case mod(rownum,2) when 1 then mod(rownum,1000) end
     , round(dbms_random.value) + 10
     , round(dbms_random.value) + 10
     , 1
from   xmltable('1 to 10000000');

create index x1 on abc (pod_cd, dt);

create index x2 on abc (fant, rce);
```

Test for nulls:

```
select count(*) from abc a
where  a.pod_cd = '367'
and    a.dt is null;

  COUNT(*)
----------
      6667

1 row selected.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2253536563

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     7 |    20   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE   |      |     1 |     7 |            |          |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| X1   |  6667 | 46669 |    20   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
2 - access("A"."POD_CD"='367' AND "A"."DT" IS NULL)
```

The query was executed using index X1, without touching the table.

Test for `fant != rce`:

```
select count(*)
from   abc a
where  a.fant != a.rce;

  COUNT(*)
----------
   5000666

1 row selected.

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 29151601

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |      |     1 |     6 |  6468   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE       |      |     1 |     6 |            |          |
|*  2 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| X2   |  5000K|    28M|  6468   (1)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
2 - filter("A"."FANT"<>"A"."RCE")
```

The query was executed using index X2, also without touching the table.

Test for the full query:

```
create index x3 on abc(pod_cd, dt, fant, rce, col_no, wt);

select round(sum(a.wt)) as a_wt
from   abc a
where  a.dt is null
and    a.col_no is not null
and    a.pod_cd = '367'
and    a.fant != a.rce;

      A_WT
----------
       481

1 row selected.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3828004431

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |    16 |    28   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE   |      |     1 |    16 |            |          |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| X3   |   476 |  7616 |    28   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   2 - access("A"."POD_CD"='367' AND "A"."DT" IS NULL)
       filter("A"."COL_NO" IS NOT NULL AND "A"."FANT"<>"A"."RCE")
```

Full table scans aren't always terrible, though.

```
SQL> drop index x1;

Index dropped.

SQL> drop index x2;

Index dropped.

SQL> drop index x3;

Index dropped.

select round(sum(a.wt)) as a_wt 
from   abc a
where  a.dt is null 
and    a.col_no is not null 
and    a.pod_cd = '367' 
and    a.fant != a.rce;

      A_WT
----------
       481

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.18

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1045519631

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     1 |    16 |  8188   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |      |     1 |    16 |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| ABC  |   476 |  7616 |  8188   (1)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   2 - filter("A"."COL_NO" IS NOT NULL AND "A"."POD_CD"='367' AND
              "A"."DT" IS NULL AND "A"."FANT"<>"A"."RCE")
```

Table ABC has 10 million rows, and the full scan took 0.18 seconds. This is in a VM on a 4 year old laptop.